# MySQL Date Between Not Working Properly

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I'm trying to get all rows that have a date between two other dates. The date field in the table is just text with the following format "dd/MM/yyyy"

I've tried this command:

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Datum)) BETWEEN DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(@ParStart)) AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(@ParStop))
```

@ParStart = "06/12/2016"
@ParStop = "05/01/2017"

Instead of returning just the data that falls between these dates, it returns everything.

I've tried using a select on the table with STR_TO_DATE but it returns null when I try this:

```
str_to_date(`Datum`, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

I also tried changing the column type to date or datetime but that deletes the dates that are in there and replaces them with 0

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot better if you had native `DATE` or `DATETIME` fields with ISO-8601 `YYYY-MM-DD` formatted dates. Using other formats is nothing but a total headache because they can't sort correctly and so can't be indexed, plus there's not always widespread agreement between `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: So much better in fact, that it's silly to answer until you do!

Answer (score 0):

`FROM_UNIXTIME` works on numbers (number of seconds since 01.01.1970 00:00), not on strings. When you use it on strings it returns the same value (01.01.1970 00:00) for every string and thus your query `WHERE` clause is always true.

You should use `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` for those kind of comparisons.

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Datum, "%d/%m/%Y") BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(@ParStart, "%d/%m/%Y") AND STR_TO_DATE(@ParStop, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

And you really should consider not storing dates in strings.